# Gradient Vector From Surface tool applying arrows to entire map instead of clipped area

Tags: qgis, saga, slope

I can't figure out why 'Gradient Vectors From Surface' started applying the arrows to the entire map instead of just the clipped area as it had when I started using the tool (see images).[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! In the first image, does the vector field actually cover the *entire* map, or only a certain extent? Also, was there anything you did differently between the two datasets (like version update, different sequence of algorithms, different settings in some algorithms, etc.)?